# Parse a sub-string with parsec (by ignoring unmatched prefixes)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I would like to extract the repository name from the first line of `git remote -v`, which is usually of the form:

```
origin git@github.com:some-user/some-repo.git (fetch)
```

I quickly made the following parser using [`parsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11):

```
-- | Parse the repository name from the output given by the first line of `git remote -v`.
repoNameFromRemoteP :: Parser String
repoNameFromRemoteP = do
    _ <- originPart >> hostPart
    _ <- char ':'
    firstPart <- many1 alphaNum
    _ <- char '/'
    secondPart <- many1 alphaNum
    _ <- string ".git"
    return $ firstPart ++ "/" ++ secondPart
    where
      originPart = many1 alphaNum >> space
      hostPart =  many1 alphaNum
               >> (string "@" <|> string "://")
               >> many1 alphaNum `sepBy` char '.'
```

But this parser looks a bit awkward. Actually I'm only interested in whatever follows the colon (`":"`), and it would be easier if I could just write a parser for it.

Is there a way to have `parsec` skip a character upon a failed match, and re-try from the next position?

Comment: Instead of `_ <- foo` it is much more common to simply write `foo`. And it is somewhat odd to separate `originPart` from `hostPart` with `>>`, but separate from `char ':'` with a newline. What's the difference? I would connect them all with `>>`.

Comment: Do you really need a parser? This looks like a job for `dropWhile`.

Comment: @gallais if you have a suggestion for how to use `dropWhile` for extracting the repository information from the first line of `git remote -v`, I'll be happy to see it. Maybe a parser is overkill, but I don't know of any other solution at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood the question, try `many (noneOf ":")`. This will consume any character until it sees a `':'`, then stop.

**Edit:** Seems I had not understood the question. You can use the `try` combinator to turn a parser which may consume some characters before failing into one that consumes no characters on a failure. So:

```
skipUntil p = try p <|> (anyChar >> skipUntil p)
```

Beware that this can be quite expensive, both in runtime (because it will try matching `p` at every position) and memory (because `try` prevents `p` from consuming characters and so the input cannot be garbage collected at all until `p` completes). You might be able to alleviate the first of those two problems by parameterizing the `anyChar` bit so that the caller could choose some cheap parser for finding candidate positions; e.g.

```
skipUntil p skipper = try p <|> (skipper >> skipUntil p skipper)
```

You could then potentially use the above `many (noneOf ":")` construction to only try `p` on positions that start with a `:`.

Comment: I agree with this solution, but it would be helpful to point out that this is suggesting a different (better) approach than what was actually asked for. Instead of "here's a parser, try it out until you find a place in the string where it matches", you should write a better parser that explicitly knows what characters to discard.

Comment: That could also work. But problem is that I might have to skip a colon (`":"`) if I have a remote repository of the form `http://...`.

Comment: @amalloy Ah! I see I had *not* understood the question. Okay, I'll add a sentence about that kind of solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

The
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap)
combinator from
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
can skip a character upon a failed match, and re-try from the next position.

Maybe this is overkill for your particular case, but it does solve the
general problem.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either

username :: Parsec Void String String
username = do
    void $ single ':'
    some $ alphaNumChar <|> single '-'

listToMaybe . rights =<< parseMaybe (sepCap username)
    "origin git@github.com:some-user/some-repo.git (fetch)"
```

```hs
Just "some-user"
```